# Is it important to upgrade kafka version from 2.8 to 3.1 and what are the advantages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What kind of benefits do you think upgrading the kafka version will provide and is it important? What are the advantages of switching from 2.8 to 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kafka release notes cover all added features and fixes. For example, as of Kafka 3.3.1 release, Zookeeper is no longer required.

Kafka 3.0 removed support for Scala 2.11, and maybe Java 7/8, and enables transactions by default, I believe.

Make sure that you read the upgrade notes for protocol changes that will make it impossible to downgrade in the event of errors.